# Why is this fixed header shifting when scrolling?

Tags: css, fixed

I have a simple fixed header, that seems to be shifting up when the body is scrolled a slight amount, but only on the homepage (and only on mobile display). Other pages are okay, so I assume it's related to an element being shown/not shown on one instance and not the other.

I can't figure out a fix for the homepage to make it stay fixed.

http://dev.bellavou.co.uk (best to inspect and use responsive design mode to view on mobile).

http://dev.bellavou.co.uk/request-a-consultation/ This shows the header staying fixed when scrolling fine.

Can anyone help identify where the issue lies?

```
body.fixed-header #header {
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain downvotes?

Comment: I'm guessing the down vote is because you have no code in your question and just links to an external site.

Comment: But that’s not true...

Comment: CSS is usually not enough. I didn't down vote, but yes, you don't have any of the HTML in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with height is caused by CSS classes that is triggered below certain point.

[image]
[image]

And it is caused by additional `minimal` CSS class that is added to `<header>` and affects many elements below in DOM structure.

[image]
[image]

You can see that for example `#branding` is affected by added `minimal` CSS class.

By the way, as you can see your header doesn't really have 100% width.

[image: As you can see this header doesn't really have 100% width.]
[image]

It's because it's CSS:

```
body.fixed-header.home #header {
    width: calc(100% - 15px);
}
```

Changing above to below fixes the issue.

```
body.fixed-header.home #header {
    width: 100%;
}
```

You styles are overwritten:

[image]

With `width: 100%`:

[image: With <code>width: 100%</code>.]

In situations like that always remember to check dev tools and track down actual, final, computed CSS styles. :).

Comment: Please read my question properly. I’m asking nothing about width.

Comment: But it is width related. Header doesn't shift, it doesn't have 100% from the beginning.

Comment: Hmm I’ll check this because I’m confused now. I know what that rule is doing cause I created it today.

Comment: I edited my answer and added one more screenshot showing what's going on. When scrolled to the top **it seems** like header has 100%, but it doesn't. You see it when scrolling down, because there's no more white background behind header.

Comment: But still, width has nothing to do with my question. My question is why is the header moving up by half it’s height when the page is scrolled down, when it has fixed position. I’m asking nothing about the width.

Comment: I edited my answer. It's because additional CSS class that is triggered below certain point in scrolling. Do you know now what to do about it?

Comment: @Lee : have my answer helped you in any way?

Comment: No, because you haven’t read or understood what my problem is, you’ve seen possibly another and decided to fix that. My question says nothing about the width or height of the header.

Comment: So could you please provide screenshot(s) showing your problem? No other 'shifting' shows up.